# Get all decimal places in a number after division

Tags: java, formatting, bigdecimal

I am currently using the BigDecimal and it is giving me more decimals but not nearly enough for what I am trying to do. I need to be able to get all the way to the 10^6 digit. This is my current code

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(103993/33102.0);
    pw.println(num.toString());
```

and it outputs **3.14159265301190249175533608649857342243194580078125**

where the number actually has a lot more decimals: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=103993%2F33102

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are loosing the precision when evaluating this:

```
103993/33102.0
```

as a double division. Actually, the following:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(103993/33102.0);
```

is equivlent to:

```
double d = 103993/33102.0;
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(d);
```

instead, use:

```
int scale = 100;
BigDecimal num1 = new BigDecimal(103993);
BigDecimal num2 = new BigDecimal(33102);
System.out.println(num1.divide(num2, scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
3.1415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737
```

Comment: in my eclipse console my output is: 3.1415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613316415926530119026040722614947737296840070086399613 is that just cause eclipse dosent want to print the whole thing out

Comment: @WillJamieson You need to make `scale = 1000000`, but believe me it will take a long time.

Comment: starting with scale = 10000 (ten thousands), it only prints "3." on my system. I wonder if it's eclipse or a Java bug...

Comment: Strangely it doesn't help but it's ok. Works on command line.

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann You are right, I change `scale` to `1000000` and after about 10 minutes, it prints `3.`.

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann The maximum length that Eclipse can handle is `scale = 4095`. If I change it to `4096`, it prints `3.`.

Comment: is there a quicker way to do this for getting 10,000 digits or is big decimal my only option?

Comment: @WillJamieson I am not sure if there are algorithms for achieving this with the primitive data types (i.e. the 64-bit double), but `BigDecimal` is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how you are making your number.  The `103993/33102.0` is evaluated as a double precision floating point expression (`double`) before the `BigDecimal` class ever gets involved.  You should make separate `BigDecimal` objects and use `BigDecimal.divide` to get the number you want.

Since you want exact results, I'd probably pass both of your numbers in as integers when starting.

Even after doing that, I doubt you'll be able to get out to the 10^6 digit.  You might need to implement your own division algorithm to get out to that level as any sane implementation of arbitrary precision math is going to stop long before that point (at least by default).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `BigDecimal` has as much precision as you want it to have (you may just wait a little longer if you want more precision, you can specify `scale` appropriately in `divide`).